# Java, Spring, Unable to find /WEB-INF/spring.properties do I need to set it somewhere besides propertyConfigurer?

Tags: java, spring, properties, classpath

I am getting an error message that `Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [WEB-INF/spring.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist`. The spring.properties files does exist and is in my /WEB-INF directory (I have confirmed that it is in my build directory after building the project). I have it set on my project's .classpath directory like this:

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring.properties"/>
```

In my Spring application context, I have it entered like this:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" 
  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="/WEB-INF/spring.properties" />
</bean>
```

I apologize if this is a basic question but I really am perplexed as to what the problem is and how to solve it, I have done a lot of searching on this and can't seem to figure it out. Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at one of my webapps that uses a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`, I see that I put the properties in `/WEB-INF/classes` and then configured the PPC to use it with a Spring `classpath:` URL; i.e.

```
    /WEB-INF/classes/substitution.properties
```

accessed as

```
    classpath:substitution.properties
```

Answer (score 3):

Spring supports a [ServletContextResource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-implementations-servletcontextresource), which you can use by leaving off the resource prefix entirely. "You will get back a Resource type that is appropriate to that particular application context", and since we are using a web context, that resource will be a ServletContextResource.

The path is from the root of your webapp. Our paths look like

```
 <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/application.properties"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your path ("src/main/webapp") suggests you are using Maven to build the project. If this is the case, put your .properties -file(s) to /src/main/resources and use "`classpath:<filename>`" to access them, everything under src/main/resources should be accessible through classpath without any further configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the file under `WEB-INF/classes/` and referring to it with `value="spring.properties"`. I think that should do the trick.

Comment: thanks for the response, I did that and am now getting `[ERROR] [main 11:00:33] (ContextLoader.java:initWebApplicationContext:220) Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/spring.properties]` I am a bit perplexed by this

Answer (score 0):

Just put the spring.properties file under the directory src/main/webapp (alongside WEB-INF) and referring to it with

```
<bean id="placeholderConfig"   
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
    <list>
        <value>spring.properties</value>
    </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```